# If G is a group, H<= G, and G=Z20, what is H=<4>?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If Z=20 and H=<4>, what is the set Z composed of? what is H=?, and what are the elements of H in G?

Also. how will I be able to graph this?

It is part of my homework that I'd rather do myself but I can't find simple examples on the internet

Comment: The notation $H = \langle 4 \rangle$ denotes the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by the element $4$, i.e. the set $\{4^{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, where in this case $4^{n}$ denotes $4$ added to itself $n$ times. See if you can't compute this.

Comment: You don't mean $Z=20$. What you mean is $G = \mathbb{Z}/20$. There is no set $Z$, but the group $G$ is composed of all equivalence classes modulo $20$ (or, if you prefer, the integers from $0$ to $19$ under addition mod $20$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to figure out what the subgroup generated by $4$ looks like, you just need to try out adding $4$ to itself a few times.

$$4+4=8, 4+4+4=12,$$

and so on. You should be able to conclude that $H$ is finite and contains five elements.

Answer (score 0):

$Z=\{1,2\dots,20\}$ and $H=\{4,8,12,16,20\}$

Comment: Come now. The original poster clearly indicated it is part of his homework and that he would like to do it himself. Simply posting the answer with no explanation or instructive context doesn't help his understanding at all.

Comment: I'm Sorry for it.

Comment: My apologies if I came off as harsh. Please consider updating your answer - it could be quite helpful with just a bit of extra content.

Comment: dont worry, I tried it myself since Paul answered. Though, I thought 20 is supposed to be zero in H now?

Comment: @ShrummsDorke: good, glad to hear it. You can think of $20$ as $0$ in $G$, but really, $G$ is the set of -equivalence classes- or integers modulo $20$; hence, any two integers that differ by a multiple of $20$ in fact represent the same equivalence class in $G$. Thus, $0$ and $20$ (sometimes written as $[0], [20]$ to avoid this confusion)  are in fact the same element of $G$. We usually just choose $[0]$ because it is convenient.

Comment: Thank you. I have this one last thing Id like to ask if you don't mind. I have another similar problem as this, although it's G is U(20) instead of Z20, how will the cosets be different?